# Does using JARM make sense when we use PKCE and PAR?

Tags: openid-connect

Following FAPI we should use JARM within authorization response (redirection to client with state and code parameter). Does it make any sense, when we use PKCE and PAR? Even if attacker take over `code` he still isn't able to get access token, because he don't know `code_verifier` and probably cannot authenticate on token endpoint. For what JARM is used and what attack it prevents? And if JARM is really needed, is it enough to just sign the response or should we sign then encrypt?